# How do I call Apache's MethodUtils methods with mocks from Mockito as paramaters?

Tags: java, apache, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

I use `org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils` ([api link](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html)) on occasion.  I generally avoid reflection, but alas this case called for it.

My problem comes to testing.  I use Mockito for mocking, and when I call `MethodUtils.invokeMethod` with a mock as an argument, MethodUtils throws a `NoSuchMethodError` because it thinks the mocked object doesn't match the parameter type.  Any suggestions?

Signature of concrete method I'm calling:

```
public void propagateMirrorRateOfferId(MasterAvailabilityRule masterAvailabilityRule)
```

My mock generation:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {

    private static final Long RATE_OFFER_ID = 1L;
    private static final Long RATE_ENTITY_ID = 2L;
    private static final Long ORIGINAL_RATE_OFFER_ID = 3L;
    private static final Long ORIGINAL_RATE_ENTITY_ID = 4L;


    @Mock MasterAvailabilityRule masterAvailabilityRule;
    PropertyAvailabilityRule propertyAvailabilityRule;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        propertyAvailabilityRule = new PropertyAvailabilityRule();
        propertyAvailabilityRule.setMirrorRateOfferId(ORIGINAL_RATE_OFFER_ID);
        propertyAvailabilityRule.setMirrorRateEntityId(ORIGINAL_RATE_ENTITY_ID);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPropagate() throws Exception {
        // arrange
        when(masterAvailabilityRule.determineAvailabilityMirroringRelationship(any(String.class))).
            thenReturn(new AvailabilityMirroringRelationship(RATE_OFFER_ID, RATE_ENTITY_ID));
        when(masterAvailabilityRule.isMirrorLocked()).
                thenReturn(true);

        // action
        SomeUtility.thatCallsMethodUtilsAndPassesThisMock(masterAvailabilityRule);

        // assert
        assertEquals("Should have updated the mirrored rate offer id.", RATE_OFFER_ID, propertyAvailabilityRule.getMirrorRateOfferId());
        assertEquals("Should have updated the mirrored rate entity id.", RATE_ENTITY_ID, propertyAvailabilityRule.getMirrorRateEntityId());


    }
}
```

### Thanks all, figured it out

In coming up with the examples for you guys, I put the MethodUtils call directly in my test and it worked.  Turns out the I had imported the MethodUtils class from `org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.MethodUtils` in my utility class.  For some reason, that version of the class fails with the mocks.  When I use `org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils` it works.  Not sure why.  Perhaps I should update my original question to ask why the one in the `reflect` package fails... Anyway, will mark my question as answered once enough time has passed for me to submit an answer.

Comment: show us the concrete methods that fail

Comment: And the mock generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the I had imported the `MethodUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.MethodUtils` in my utility class. For some reason, that version of the class fails with the mocks. When I use `org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils` it works.